# Hamburger navbar toggle from template won't work on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

Hamburger wont toggle in mobile view on Rails...

I have an issue with the navbar button in rails that I got from a template. The navbar button toggle however it will respond to a click event and console log that it has been clicked.

The template seems to do fine in a browser but once in rails it refuses to work. I have added the code to the main app.js file to see if it was an asset pipeline issue and for brevity as the js file that comes with the template is 30k lines long

I have tried turning on and off turbolinks. A console log shows that the jquery is responding to the click event, however the navbar still will not toggle so it seems like code is being accessed fine. Debugging js in chrome was unfruitful as the click event was passed around some parent and child element when stepping.

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require page
//= require script
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require activestorage
//= require_tree .


 /**
  * page is the main js file, loaded from vendor/assets
 */


$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {
    page.initNavbar = function() {

        /**
         * Toggle navbar
         */
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar-toggler', function() {
          page.navbarToggle();
          console.log("navbar licked")
        });


        /**
         * Tapping on the backdrop will close the navbar
         */
        $(document).on('click', '.backdrop-navbar', function() {
          page.navbarClose();
        });


        /**
         * Toggle menu open on small screen devices
         */
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar-open .nav-navbar > .nav-item > .nav-link', function() {
          $(this).closest('.nav-item').siblings('.nav-item').find('> .nav:visible').slideUp(333, 'linear');
          $(this).next('.nav').slideToggle(333, 'linear');
        });

      }


      page.navbarToggle = function() {
        var body   = page.body,
            navbar = page.navbar;

        body.toggleClass('navbar-open');
        if (body.hasClass('navbar-open')) {
          navbar.prepend('<div class="backdrop backdrop-navbar"></div>');
        }
      }

      page.navbarClose = function() {
        page.body.removeClass('navbar-open');
        $('.backdrop-navbar').remove();
      }

});
```

The erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-stick-dark" data-navbar="smart">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-left mr-4">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">&#9776;</button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <%= link_to root_url do %>
           <% if controller_name == "home" %>
            <%= image_tag 'uproar-light.png', class: 'navbar-brand'%>
            <% else %>
            <%= image_tag 'uproar-dark.png', class: 'navbar-brand'%>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </a>
        </div>

        <section class="navbar-mobile">
          <nav class="nav nav-navbar mr-auto">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-features">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-pricing">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </nav>

          <div class="d-none d-stick-block">
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-light ml-lg-5 mr-2" href="#">Login</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#">Sign up</a>
          </div>
        </section>

      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing around I finally got the navbar toggle to work by putting the javascript include tags in the footer.

Seems like the JS included in the theme needed to load last in order to work. This is typical outside Rails however I found away to make the javascript load asynchronously without having to annoy turbolinks.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", async: true %>
```

Added async: true to each of the javascript tags and toggle is working. Moved the include tags back to the header.